# Error when copying worksheet in Excel VBA "We couldn't copy this sheet."

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a code sample from https://trumpexcel.com/split-each-excel-sheet-into-separate-files/ to split an excel workbook into one file per worksheet.

I encountered the error `Run-time error '1004': We couldn't copy this sheet.'

```
'Code Created by Sumit Bansal from trumpexcel.com
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the macro was tripping up when it encountered a hidden worksheet.
To fix this I updated the script to ignore hidden worksheets.

Final result

```
'Code Created by Sumit Bansal from trumpexcel.com
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Visible <> xlSheetHidden Then
        ws.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm unable to comment on the original article so posting the fix here.
If you need to copy hidden sheets, you'll probably have to unhide it, copy the sheet, and then hide it again.